# storing images in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to store my images in an array named **"_images"** but if I use `NSLog()` to view the data stored in image array, I get only one image. Would you guys help me out? Here's my code:

```
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo1.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo2.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo3.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo4.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo5.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo6.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo7.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo8.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo9.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo10.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo11.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo12.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo13.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo14.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo15.png"]];
_images =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo16.png"]];

NSLog(@"ha ha ha:%d",_images.count);
```

Comment: This re-creates the array each time!

Comment: Please try to use reasonable grammar and spelling when you post questions. Questions that look like they were written by the Chik-fil-A cows are harder to read, less likely to be taken seriously, and less likely to get gud ansers.

Comment: especially from vegetarians. or chickens. or vegetarian chickens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're creating a new array on each line; you lose the reference to the old array and thus the image within it. You want to add new images to an existing array. Change lines 2 and onwards to the following:

```
[_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:...]];
```

Comment: did u  get the array description @kingston

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a loop:

```
_images = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
for (int i=1; i<=16; ++i) {
  [_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"logo%d.png",i]]];
}
```

Comment: Note that you can use `_images = [NSMutableArray array]` instead.